# how to customize select loop in bash

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, fedora

I was wondering if is possible customize the select loop for bash.

**I have this code:**

```
select varName in list
do
case $varName in
    pattern1)
        command1;;
    pattern2)
        command2;;
    pattern1)
        command3;;
    *)
        echo "Error select option 1..3";;
esac            
done
```

**Output is something like this:**

```
 1) columbia    3) challenger  5) atlantis    7) pathfinder
 2) endeavour   4) discovery   6) enterprise
 #?
```

I would like to order the options in landscape view and also change the prompt [#?] by something else

Thanks

Comment: This question might be better suited for: http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`select` displays the `PS3` prompt.

You could try something like:

```
echo $PS3
old_PS3=$PS3
export PS3="make a selection :D"
list='columbia challenger atlantis pathfinder endeavour discovery enterprise'
select varName in $list
do
case $varName in
    pattern1)
        command1;;
    pattern2)
        command2;;
    pattern1)
        command3;;
    *)
        echo "Error select option 1..3";;
esac            
done
# set PS3 back to original
export PS3=$old_PS3
```

Comment: This works thanks, and what about landscape view ?  , i appreciate it ;)

Comment: @shaveax Without getting into some quirky things using awk, and setting IFS and OFS, i would suggest looking into something like `whiptail` if you want to format the menus.

Comment: Also see: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203309/can-i-change-how-select-options-are-displayed basically instead of trying to force `select` into a format you could use different tools to do the formatting something like `column` or `printf` or just plain old `echo` and a `case` statement.